# AngularJS - $compile-ing an element and passing the scope to it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple directive:

```
<div my-directive>
    <span ng-click="reveal()">Click Me</span>
    <!-- And other stuff -->
</div>
```

When I press `Click Me`, a modal opens up with a form for you to edit some content. All these contents are to part of the `scope.form` data. For now, say this object only has one entry called `name`.

So this is what I did for my directive:

```
scope.reveal = function()
{
   var el = $compile('<input type="text" ng-model="scope.form.name" />')(scope);

   // Now launch the modal
}
```

So the modal does open up and the content of `scope.form.name` is shown correctly. However, if I close the modal, and open it again, the value is not saved (i.e, the `scope.form.name` is not updated inside the directive).

What's the best I can do this?

Comment: is your directive running with an 'isolated' scope by any chance?

Comment: please make example in fiddle

Comment: @NarekMamikonyan, okay I will very soon.

Comment: ok, I guess we will wait for your fiddle then. Just curious, have you tried inspecting the scope in the Batarang [https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang]? That might give you some clue about what is happening to the scope once you close the modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With angularjs you usually don't compile and add elements to the DOM. You should declare your form in your template and bind ng-show to a property on the scope to show/hide your form.

```
<div my-directive>
    <span ng-click="form.show = true">Click Me</span>
    <form ng-show="form.show">
        <input type="text" ng-model="form.name" />
    <form>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I realize that. But what I actually have is a modal module that is used for any kind of pop-in panel. Now, in this page, I have a list of users. On click on a user, I want to open up the modal, load the user profile and edit it, and then save and close it. So I can't really load the form prior to this.